# Where should this question go?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Hi I wrote a question [asking the community where it gets its ideas from, to prompt some discussion on self-improvement in the generic sense.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201855/where-do-people-draw-inspiration-for-personal-coding-projects) While I don't want to get into an argument on whether it should have been closed, I'm curious to know where it should go instead?

Given that its not directly related to a programming problem, its not really in the scope of StackOverflow; its not about programming in the workplace, so that rules out The Workplace; nor is it really about computer science or maths.

So if its not appropriate for Programmers, where would one ask fellow programmers how they go about improving their skills and identifying appropriate problems to explore new programming paradigms as an important part of self-improvement?

Comment: A great deal of the site's design is based on avoiding discussion, though this isn't entirely obvious at first glance.  The goal is authoritative answers.

Comment: take a look at site **[about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/about)** page: "This site is all about getting answers. It's _not a discussion forum_..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that it's a polling question. The problem with polling questions is that they don't converge toward a single answer or set of answers. You could keep adding answers indefinitely and they'd still be just as valid.

While this in and of itself is not a bad thing, it's not what the Stack Exchange was built to do. Reddit, Quora, or Hacker News are more suitable platforms for this sort of question but have a correspondingly higher level of "noise" than we do.

Comment: Ok thats a fair call.

Comment: Chat is a good place for discussions as well as it is much, much more loosely scoped than the sites proper.

Comment: relevant line from the faq "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."